# How do I install the amdgpu-install .deb file?

Tags: drivers, software-installation, deb, amdgpu

I'm new just joined up today and installed Ubuntu. When I attempt to install `amdgpu-install_22.20.50200-1_all.deb` latest AMD driver I get this error:

```
E: Unable to locate package amdgpu-install_22.20.50200-1_all.deb
```

The command I'm using:

```
sudo apt install -f /amdgpu-install_22.20.50200-1_all.deb
```

Can someone help me out? I get the same error when attempting to install Microsoft Edge. Thank you!

Comment: have you tried giving it the path to the .deb file?

Comment: Don't do that! Since today is your first day, I will tell you the first rule of using Ubuntu. Always install from the repository if possible. Go to the app **Software and Updates**. Look for the tab **Additional Drivers**. Choose the driver you want from there. You will need a very good reason (edit your question and explain why) you are trying to do it the way you are trying.

Comment: Emphasis on the `./` in @Quasímodo's comment. You have just `/` in your command, @Levi.

Comment: Do not do that since amdgpu in probably already in your kernel driver.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to define either what you need to install it in terms of where it can be found on the drive or where you need to access it from, so like this

```
dpkg -i *.deb
```

Replace `*.deb` with the path and name of the package you downloaded.

Answer (score -1):

Try `sudo dpkg -i <path/to/deb>`, make sure `<path/to/deb>` is corrent.